# How to send email confirmation for signup users using django rest api

Tags: django-rest-framework

Created drf api for signup with email,once user signup with email,then user should be able to get email sms otp and  that otp should valid for two minutes, these we have to implement using django rest framework. Please any reference

Answer (score 0):

You can try `django-djoser`[link](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) if you need to change the default behaviour or do customization you can overwrite relevant functionality. [source code](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser)